# Import Python referenced scripts in R scripts

Tags: python, r, shiny

anyone knows how to import two python scripts? In function1.py contains the function (for example "sum") needs to importing function2.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python(".venv/bin/python", required=T)
reticulate::source_python("./utilities/function1.py") # import function2
reticulate::source_python("./utilities/function2.py")
```

Then the error comes with that

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: No module named 'sum'
```

Comment: does the order matter here? can you source `function2.py` first?

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your reply! i also tried to import the function2.py first but still the error comes with the function1.py can't import the "sum" in  function2